# Message box based on time and range value

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Still rather new to the whole excel VBA thing. Ideally I would like some code to be able to perform the following function.

Here's my example;

I have roughly 20 rows of data, column (A) holds references within, column (B) with the date of application, column (C) with formula to calculate elapsed time period, and column (D) states "TRUE" or "FALSE" if time period specified has passed.

What I would like to happen is at a specific time of day, say 11:00am I would like a message box to appear showing the text "Chase Documents". this would only appear if the following condition has been met, text in column D:D = "TRUE". if "FALSE" then ignore.

I would only like this message to appear at the specified time given and not each time data was entered into the worksheet.

Is it also possible to reference another cell from the same row? and have it show within the text box? e.g. text box appears with the text "Chase Documents" along with the value from column (A).

I understand this might not be possible, but any help with this would be appreciated.

This is as far as I have got with the code;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Range("D:D").Find(what:="TRUE", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "CHASE Documents!!"
    End If
   End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Open()


    Application.OnTime TimeValue("11:00:00"), "Change"

    End Sub
```

I keep running into an error message with the above code.

What I ideally want is a reminder at a certain time point in the day, stating that documents need to be chased based on the values in a specified column.

Again any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: you could schedule the file to open at 11:00 and have a msgbox popup on file open.  is this file just left open at all times or what?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ??

Comment: Cyril - The workbook is opened all day as is periodically updated throughout the day. Thanks.

Comment: Add  Private Sub Change()  because  "Change" was the procedure name that OnTime was given.

Answer (score 0):

You've been pretty close with your code:

**In `ThisWorkbook` add this:**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("11:00:00"), "ChaseDocs"

End Sub
```

**In any `module`, add this (and change sheet name):**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ChaseDocs()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Your Sheet Name Here")

Dim rngSrc As Range
Set rngSrc = ws.Range("D:D").Find(what:="TRUE", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

    If Not rngSrc Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "CHASE Documents!!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & rngSrc.Offset(, -3).Value
        'vbCrLf ==> means new line
        'rngSrc.Offset(, -3).Value ==> means get the value 3 columns to the left from current position
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing! exactly what I needed! Thank you for the quick response :)